# design restful web service to handle 150 requests per second

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

How many options do we have to design restful web service to handle 150 requests per second.

1) Asynchronous rest service using messaging seems better option for me

Comment: Do you have only GET requests or you need PUT/DELETE/POST as well in 150 rps. Technically, if you do the sizing right ( hardware, etc) any model would be able to handle this load.